# How to name a variable or data.frame with the date in R

Tags: r, datetime, naming

I have a function that outputs a data frame, and I would like it to name the data with the current date somewhere in the name. Ideally, something like 20170517.data or the like.

If I can figure out how to name just an object or variable like this, I can include it in my function.

I've tried:

```
as.character(sys.Date,date) <- dataframe
paste(sys.Date,data,sep="") <- dataframe
```

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: Do you want to save the dataframe as a file named `20170517.data`? Or do you want this to be your R object name?

Comment: TheBiro - the object, not the file. Jav's solution works!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `assign`

```
my_data <- rnorm(10)
assign(paste0(Sys.Date(), ".data"), value = my_data)
```

This will create variable of the form "2017-05-17.data".

Comment: but to access that variable you will have to wrap the name in quotes.

Comment: Yes, this is actually a terrible naming scheme. OP, you will be better off to start with character letter: "data_2017-05-17". And, put them all in a single list. So you will not clutter your environment with bunch of data_* variables.

Comment: Jav, that's how I ended up doing it. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to create a dfname(sys.date) straight from an excel file (or other) you can use `assign(paste0("prefix",Sys.Date()), value = read_excel("/directory/filename.xlsx"))`